# check if parent record has any child records with start_date in the future then stop update rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have table called items and i have a method that called archive in the items_controller.rb, if the method gets called it sets the active field on the item to false.  the issue is i have another table called reservations and a field on it called start_date so i want before it update the  active field on item to false, i want to check if their is any reservations with start_date field in the future. if there is then do not update the active field on item and give a user an error message.

here is item.rb

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :reservations
 before_save :check_for_reservations
 def check_for_reservations
   if reservations.count > 0
     reservations.each do |reservation|
       if reservation.start_date > Date.today
       return false
      end
     end
   end
 end
end
```

here is items.controller.rb

```
 def archive
 @item = Item.find(params[:id])
 @item.active = false

 if @item.save
    flash[:notice] = "Item been archived..."
 else
    flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong..."
 end
   redirect_back(fallback_location: request.referer)
 end
```

is not working its updating the item record the active equal = false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be reasonable to use a custom validation method which you can read about in the [guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods). It might look something like this:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reservations
  before_save :check_for_reservations

  validate :okay_to_archive

  def okay_to_archive
    if !item.active && reservations.where("start_date >= ?", Date.today).any? 
      errors.add(:active, "can't be set to false when there are future reservations")
    end
  end

end
```

`!item.active` checks to see if the `active` attribute is not `true` (either `nil` or `false`). And `reservations.where("start_date >= ?", Date.today).any?` checks to see if there are any associated `reservations` that have a `start_date` that comes after today. So, together:

```
if !item.active && reservations.where("start_date >= ?", Date.today).any? 
  ...
end
```

they check to see if the `item` is inactive with future reservations. If so, then an error is written to the `errors`:

```
errors.add(:active, "can't be set to false when there are future reservations")
```

and when you try to do `@item.save`, you'll get a validation error.

```
def archive
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  @item.active = false

  if @item.save
    flash[:notice] = "Item been archived..."
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong..."
  end
  redirect_back(fallback_location: request.referer)
end
```

Code is not tested, but should be close.